# Program Director file with actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe-director

I have been programming flash/actionscript for a number of years; is there a way I could make a Flash/AS3 project and export it as a .dir project? Or if there is a way to use AS3 as the language in Director?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make calls to and from AS3 and Lingo, although they are asynchronous calls, so you have to be careful not to rely on the calls being executed immediately. You can insert an .SWF file into a Director file, but you cannot modify the .SWF file directly in Director. Working between the two can be fairly tedious, and I would not recommend it unless you have a good reason.

If you are taking a course on Director, I would recommend that you learn Director and Lingo. There is limited expertise available on those, and it can make you more employable if you know how to work with them.

Comment: You will not be "more employable" if you have Director/Lingo on you CV. It is out-dated technology. But it saying that, there are a few Director features that I miss in Flash!

Comment: Interesting that you should say that. First, Adobe released Director 11 last year, which means that it isn't completely outdated. Second, one of my clients is building an app using a mix of Flash and Director with Lingo scripting, since Flash couldn't do some of the things required for his app. 
Knowing another language/platform never hurts, and it will increase your employability.